# Can I start a new application but inside a "frame" I have created?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Is it possible to from my application to start another (any other) application, but the new application to be displayed inside a "frame" I have created?

Answer (score 3):

Not generally. You cannot embed the UI of another app in your app. The primary exception to that is via app widgets, if you implement an `AppWidgetHost`.

Comment: To give you a context of what I am interested in doing: I want to know if there is a way to open a new application from my application but add some kind of back button in the new app to my app. Can I do this?

Comment: @Jim: Well, the normal behavior of the device BACK button will return control to your app, assuming that the other app has not overridden this for some reason.

Comment: Yes I understand this, but is it technically possible?

Comment: @Jim: Not really. You have no way of controlling the UI of another app, such as injecting a button into it. You can show a `Notification` and stuff, but that is not tied to the other app.

Comment: Not even in the action bar? Or somehow add a "fake" header just above it?

Comment: @Jim: Fortunately, no, for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to from my app to start another (any other) application but the new application to be displayed inside a frame I have created?

Basically, not. When you start an application component registered within another application manifest file, a new process for this component will be created (if not already running) and the component will run within the newly created application process. Although for a user it looks like it's running within your app.

[App Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html#Components) (at the end of the section) might clarify some aspects.

**Edit (with respect to the comments)**:

You can't add a new UI control (talking about `Activities`) to the component of the newly started (or brought to foreground) application by the reason of running on different process.

Comment: Check my comments please for context

Comment: @Jim _"Yes I understand this, but is it technically possible?"_ It is not. The only control (as I see) you have over a newly open app is to force-closing it from your app (which, I'm pretty sure, would require `su`)...