# Implementing a container App for Android apps?

Tags: android

I  need to create a container Application in android in which I can launch and manage some of android apps.I have just started with android programming so I have very less knowledge how to go about it,it will be helpful if some one can give me some documentation references/links/sample projects which can help me out.

Comment: are you looking for some thing like app locker or launcher ?

Comment: @Sree  Something like sandbox but not very heavy .I should be able to authenticate all the apps running in my container with one credentials and restrict certain services for them.It should able to launch them ,navigate between them

Comment: kiosk mode on android is a good topic for you, search on that, you will get a good idea

Comment: If I understood you correctly you cannot do this. Probably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210459/can-i-start-a-new-application-but-inside-a-frame-i-have-created/35210565#35210565) is what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to control several applications from one application, for that you need device administrator permission. Check the following link.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html