# add another app inside my app?

Tags: android, usb

my goal is to get a video from a usb connected device (an easycap video grabber) displayed. There is already an android app that does exactly that. However i need to add some buttons and some extra functions to it. So i came to the idea of displaying the app that already exists inside my app. Is that possible in any way?
I already tried to decompile the existing app to edit the code a bit but i didn't get anything to work with.
Do you have any other idea? If you know how to program that please let me know what i need to achieve that.

Thank you!

Comment: [Can I start a new application but inside a “frame” I have created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210459/can-i-start-a-new-application-but-inside-a-frame-i-have-created)

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done due to security reasons in the Android OS itself.

Android provides a security layer called the `Sandbox` in which the OS assigns a User ID for each app, so that an app will not have permission to access resources from another app.