# Android - Open up Bluetooth setting, but in another view

Tags: android, android-settings

I know that to open up the Bluetooth settings programmatically.

I do something like this:

```
Intent intentOpenBluetoothSettings = new Intent();
intentOpenBluetoothSettings.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS); 
startActivity(intentOpenBluetoothSettings);
```

But doing so will take me to the Bluetooth settings page in the same view/application.

How should I go about if I want the Bluetooth settings page to open up in another view/window/page, outside the application?.

The reason why I want this to be done is so that the user will not confuse the settings page and my app.

Thanks.

***Update***

I tried doing `intentOpenBluetoothSettings.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`

But no luck in getting it to open in another view.

Comment: What settings do you want to change? A better alternative might be to show the dialog for enabling Bluetooth and then have an activity in your app where you search for devices and connect to them.

Comment: I want to take the user to the Bluetooth settings page for them to connect to Bluetooth. But I want the Settings page to be outside of my app. Thanks.

Comment: _"But doing so will take me to the Bluetooth settings page in the same view/application."_ It isn't correct. See [Can I start a new application but inside a “frame” I have created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210459/can-i-start-a-new-application-but-inside-a-frame-i-have-created)

Comment: ^^^ So it's not possible? @Onik

Comment: Bluetooth settings are opened in its dedicated process, NOT in your app's process.

Comment: Why is it in the same view/process/window when I open up settings?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of requesting for enabling Bluetooth:

```
intentOpenBluetoothSettings.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
```

or

```
intentOpenBluetoothSettings.setAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
```

If none of them suit your needs, then you might rethink your idea.

Comment: I tried the first one. There's no problem of opening the Bluetooth settings page. It works fine. But I want it so it opens in another view, outside of my app. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I advice reading up a little on android activity lifecycle and backstack.

Settings is NOT running in your app.
But normally everything you start is put on the backstack.
So if you go from your app to some other app (settings) android will remember that.
Your app there is not destroyed but only set on pause (onPause is called).

If you close settings it will return to your app and delete the entry for settings on backstack. I assume that is not the problem here.

But if you don't close settings and then by some means try to start your app again it is not destroyed but only waked up (no onCreate but only onResume). Android will then check that your app has loaded settings currently and settings will show up again.

If you restart your app with an Intent you control (like from a service)
You can:

```
startMyAppIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

The flag will kill the backstack up to the point where your app is on top of the stack so your app will start no matter if it had started settings before. 
Backstack is not cleared completely so if your app was started by another app you may be able to return to that when pressing the back button.